# VS 2008 freezes after Build, Rebuild and Clean

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

My solution has 60 projects...

When I click Rebuild, Build or Clean in VS 2008, it takes long time to complete the action.

Status Bar is updating with Build/Clean Succeeded. After that VS freezes for many seconds and the CPU usage is high. Then Build Output Window updates with "========== Build: 60 succeeded" message.

This also happens if I compile a single project, even if no assembles (other than BCL) are referred.

Previously build outputs of all projects are configured to be in a central location. I am facing this issue after modifying all the projects output path to "bin\" folder.

Also, "Copy to Local" for the references are set to False to avoid multiple copies of a dll.

Thanks for any insight in this regard.